# stop javascript till jquery trigger finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this code and what i want is that function b to run only after function a is completed. the problem is: function b does not wait until ajax is complete 

 i tried when -> done and call back and don't work always alert 1 then 3 then 2
so can anyone help me.

note : this is not the real code, it's just sample one of it cause the file is about 500 lines

in the real code this will happen more than one time when the page is loaded for "first time"

 index.php

```
<select id="first_select">
    <option value=''>select one</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
<select id="second_select">
</select>
<div id="result">test</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#first_select").change(function(){
            first=$(this).val();
            $.post("test.php",{first:first},function(result){
                $("#second_select").empty();
                $("#second_select").append(result);
                alert(2);
            });
            alert(1);
        });
        $("#second_select").change(function(){
            second=$(this).val();
            $("#result").text(second);
            alert(3);
        });
        function a(callback){
            $("#first_select").val(1);
            $("#first_select").trigger('change');
            callback();
        }
        function b(){
            $("#second_select").val(4);
            $("#second_select").trigger('change');
        }
        /*$.when( a() ).done(function() {
            b();
        });*/
        /*$.when( a() ).then(function() {
            b();
        });*/
        a(function(){ b();});

    });
</script>
```

test.php

```
<?php
    echo "<option value=''>select one</option>";
    echo "<option value='",$_POST['first']+3,"'>",$_POST['first']+3,'</option>';
    echo "<option value='",$_POST['first']+4,"'>".$_POST['first']+4,'</option>';
?>
```

what i want is function b run after trigger done from function a only, so if it is triggered by user it won't run

Comment: if someone find more suitable title edit this one or tell me and i will edit it

Comment: Have you looked into promises?

Comment: you need to pass your callback to the ajax call if you want to execute b after it has finished. It makes sense that it would appear 1,3,2 at the moment.

Comment: but how to prevent call b from call when triggred by the user ?

Comment: Sleep Deprived Bulbasaur no i don't what promises is

Comment: ajax can be "synchronic" but I do not recommend that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to achieve, but I think this should do it (whatever it is?!).
The only changes I've made is set the callback to a variable and then it is executed if it exists. You'll need to clear this variable then by setting it to null or whatever if you don't want it to execute on future changes (I don't know if you do or not want this.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var myCallback;
        $("#first_select").change(function(){
            first=$(this).val();
            $.post("test.php",{first:first},function(result){
                $("#second_select").empty();
                $("#second_select").append(result);
                alert(2);
                // Check if there was a callback set that we want to run.
                if(myCallback){
                   myCallback();
                }
            });
            alert(1);
        });

        $("#second_select").change(function(){
            second=$(this).val();
            $("#result").text(second);
            alert(3);
        });

        function a(callback){
            // Set the callback.
            myCallback = callback;
            $("#first_select").val(1);
            $("#first_select").trigger('change');                
        }

        function b(){
            $("#second_select").val(4);
            $("#second_select").trigger('change');
        }

        a(function(){ b();});

    });
```

Comment: this solve the problem in the sample code and can solve it at the real one thanx :D
i will try it with the real code then tell you the result

Answer (score 0):

Use semaphore in js:

```
//
//Simple counting semaphore used at asinc call to test end execution to R&R and BIN
//
function CountingSemaphores()
{
    this._semaphore = 0;
    this.wait = function ()
    {
        this._semaphore--;
    };
    this.signal = function ()
    {
        this._semaphore++;
    };
    this.green = function ()
    {
        this._semaphore = 0;
    }
    this.cross = function ()
    {
        return (this._semaphore >= 0);
    }
}
```

use like:

```
var semaphore = new CountingSemaphores();
```

Validation:

```
function wait_for_green()
{
    if (!semaphore.cross())
    return false;
    else
    return true;
}
function start_consumming()
{
  //large processing
  semaphore.signal();
}

function main()
{
    semaphore.wait();
    start_consumming()
    while (wait_for_green())
    {
       //delay something 
     }
    //start processing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to chain tasks each then should return the promise that belongs to the current task, try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var callback = function () {
            console.log(3);
        };

        $("#first_select").change(function () {
            first = $(this).val();
            $.post("/echo/json", {
                first: first
            }).then(function (result) { // alert(2)
                console.log(2);
                $("#second_select").empty();
                /*
                 * Maybe you are missing the following return
                 */
                return $("#second_select").append(result); //then shoud return a promise.
            }).then(function (data) { //alert(3)
                callback();
            });
            console.log(1);
        });

    });
```

Fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ror0pbne/1/)